# How to display CJK Extension H?

Tags: fonts

[CJK Unified Ideographs Extension H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_H) has just been released [this week](https://unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/).

[BabelStone Han](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) only has:

> 53.6%

coverage of CJK Ext. H.

---

[HanaMin](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/) seems to have fallen off the face of the earth. They did not even release an update for CJK Ext. G.

---

Which fonts give 100% support for CJK Ext. H?

(Maybe Tianheng (天珩)?)

Comment: What do I have with these fonts that I don't already have? Rare characters?

Comment: @Pedroski For the average layperson I suppose you would be correct. There are a handful of characters that I've been waiting years on for encoding - so there are some more practical uses.

Comment: I installed them anyway, Years ago maybe, I needed a rare character, was it you who told me to install.HAN NOM A and HAN NOM B to get Vietnamese Chinese characters?

Comment: @Pedroski Haha, maybe?! We would need to find the thread, I think. Those do sound like the correct fonts for Chu Nom coverage though.

Answer (score 4):

**遍黑体**

There's an active font project Plangothic. https://github.com/Fitzgerald-Porthmouth-Koenigsegg/Plangothic

From its creators,

> 遍黑体项目的目标是基于思源黑体的中国大陆字形对中日韩越统一表意文字扩展区进行补充

Now Ext-D/G/H has been completed and they're finishing off Ext-C.

The font file PlangothicP2-Regular.ttf covers all Ext-H characters

**全宋体**

https://fgwang.blogspot.com/2022/09/unicode-15.html

Ext-H is updated.

Comment: Haha, this is quite nice - didn't know Eiso was involved!

Comment: @Mou某 Found a new one, 全宋体.